# Replacing values in a string using recursion in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to repalce values into a string based on the column 'Yearmonth' and 'Timedimensiondate' in the 'Mathlogictable' shown in below code....

I was able to do it successfully but now I need to replace the string with zero values which are not there in the Mathlogictable.

For eg: if you execute the below code we can find the first row having values for import-consumptionqty1(314) but not for import consumtionQty(1539)..... like

```
  YEARMONTH         OUTPUTFORMULA                                   TIMEDIMENSIONDATE                 
  CV(N1)  2002: 10  236846.000 + Import - Consumption qty1(1539)    2002-10-01
```

I need to replace the strings which doesn't have values to zero in the formula column...... such that my output should be like

```
Yearmonth           Formula         TimeDimensionDate      
CV(N1)  2002: 10    236846.000 + 0  2002-10-01
```

How can I achieve this ?

Please note that i have created a tem table called #tablevaluedfunction and inserted the output in that table.... and made a join.....

Below is the code i'm trying

```
Begin
CREATE TABLE #MathLogicTable
(
IDNUM INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
FORMULA Varchar(160),
INPUTName varchar(160),
AttributeValue Decimal(15,3),
yearmonth varchar(160),
TimeDimensionDate date
)

INSERT INTO #MathLogicTable (FORMULA,INPUTName,AttributeValue,yearmonth,TimeDimensionDate)
VALUES ('Import - Consumption qty1(314) + Import - Consumption qty1(1539)','Import - Consumption qty1(1539)',855,'CV(N1)  2002: 1','2002-01-01')
,('Import - Consumption qty1(314) + Import - Consumption qty1(1539)','Import - Consumption qty1(1539)',4860,'CV(N1)  2002: 2','2002-02-01')
,('Import - Consumption qty1(314) + Import - Consumption qty1(1539)','Import - Consumption qty1(1539)',21683,'CV(N1)  2002: 3','2002-03-01')
,('Import - Consumption qty1(314) + Import - Consumption qty1(1539)','Import - Consumption qty1(1539)',12800,'CV(N1)  2002: 4','2002-04-01')
,('Import - Consumption qty1(314) + Import - Consumption qty1(1539)','Import - Consumption qty1(1539)',802,'CV(N1)  2002: 5','2002-05-01')
,('Import - Consumption qty1(314) + Import - Consumption qty1(1539)','Import - Consumption qty1(314)',250616,' CV(N1)  2002: 6 ','2002-06-01')
,('Import - Consumption qty1(314) + Import - Consumption qty1(1539)','Import - Consumption qty1(314)',333064,' CV(N1)  2002: 7 ','2002-07-01')
,('Import - Consumption qty1(314) + Import - Consumption qty1(1539)','Import - Consumption qty1(314)',131397,' CV(N1)  2002: 8 ','2002-08-01')
,('Import - Consumption qty1(314) + Import - Consumption qty1(1539)','Import - Consumption qty1(314)',294510,' CV(N1)  2002: 9 ','2002-09-01')
,('Import - Consumption qty1(314) + Import - Consumption qty1(1539)','Import - Consumption qty1(314)',236846,' CV(N1)  2002: 10 ','2002-10-01')
,('Import - Consumption qty1(314) + Import - Consumption qty1(1539)','Import - Consumption qty1(314)',397183,' CV(N1)  2002: 11 ','2002-11-01')
,('Import - Consumption qty1(314) + Import - Consumption qty1(1539)','Import - Consumption qty1(314)',128616,' CV(N1)  2002: 12 ','2002-12-01')

;WITH cteSplitFormula AS (
    SELECT
       IDNUM
       ,TimeDimensionDate
       ,CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(FORMULA, PATINDEX('%[+\*/^]%',FORMULA+'+')-1))) AS VARCHAR(5000)) AS FormulaItem
       ,STUFF(FORMULA, 1, PATINDEX('%[+\*/^]%',FORMULA+'+'), '')  as RemainingFromula
    FROM
       #MathLogicTable

    UNION ALL
    SELECT
       IDNUM
       ,TimeDimensionDate
       ,CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(RemainingFromula, PATINDEX('%[+\*/^]%',RemainingFromula+'+')-1))) AS VARCHAR(5000)) AS FormulaItem
       ,STUFF(RemainingFromula, 1, PATINDEX('%[+\*/^]%',RemainingFromula+'+'), '')  as RemainingFromula
    FROM
       cteSplitFormula
    WHERE 
       LEN(RemainingFromula) > 0

)

, ctePartsValues AS (
    SELECT
       sf.IDNUM
       ,sf.TimeDimensionDate
       ,sf.FormulaItem AS FormulaItem
       ,ISNULL(m.AttributeValue,0) AS ReplacementValue
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sf.IDNUM ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS [ReplacementOrderID]
    FROM
       cteSplitFormula sf
       FULL OUTER JOIN #MathLogicTable m
       ON sf.FormulaItem = LTRIM(RTRIM(m.INPUTName))
       AND sf.TimeDimensionDate = m.TimeDimensionDate
)

, cteRecursiveDataSource AS (
    SELECT
       m.IDNUM
       ,REPLACE(m.Formula,pv.FormulaItem,pv.ReplacementValue) as Formula
       ,pv.ReplacementOrderID
    FROM
       #MathLogicTable m
       INNER JOIN ctePartsValues pv
       ON m.IDNUM = pv.IDNUM
       AND pv.ReplacementOrderID = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       rds.IDNUM
       ,REPLACE(rds.Formula,pv.FormulaItem,pv.ReplacementValue) as Formula
       ,pv.ReplacementOrderID
    FROM
       cteRecursiveDataSource rds
       INNER JOIN ctePartsValues pv
       ON rds.IDNUM = pv.IDNUM
       AND rds.ReplacementOrderID + 1 = pv.ReplacementOrderID
)

, cteIdentifyRowWithLastReplacementStatement AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IDNUM ORDER BY ReplacementOrderId DESC) as FinalRow
    FROM
       cteRecursiveDataSource
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cteIdentifyRowWithLastReplacementStatement
WHERE
    FinalRow = 1


DROP table #MathLogicTable
END
```

Thanks

Comment: @Matt: I have done some edits hope now its clear.... in the previous comment you mentioned that you did'nt get the recursive table code that's why i mentioned to execute the code... I apprectiate your help and suggestions...

Comment: Yes what you said is true.....I have only half of the data here(and that's the point i need to replace the missing data with Zero in the formula)... there will be more sides in the formula.... there will be any mathematical symbol as long as dynamic sql does it.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cteSplitFormula AS (
    SELECT
       IDNUM
       ,TimeDimensionDate
       ,CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(REPLACE(Formula,'Import -','ImportReplaced'), PATINDEX('%[+-\*/^]%',REPLACE(Formula,'Import -','ImportReplaced')+'+')-1))) AS VARCHAR(5000)) AS FormulaItem
       ,STUFF(REPLACE(Formula,'Import -','ImportReplaced'), 1, PATINDEX('%[+-\*/^]%',REPLACE(Formula,'Import -','ImportReplaced')+'+'), '')  as RemainingFromula
    FROM
       #MathLogicTable

    UNION ALL
    SELECT
       IDNUM
       ,TimeDimensionDate
       ,CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(RemainingFromula, PATINDEX('%[+-\*/^]%',RemainingFromula+'+')-1))) AS VARCHAR(5000)) AS FormulaItem
       ,STUFF(RemainingFromula, 1, PATINDEX('%[+-\*/^]%',RemainingFromula+'+'), '')  as RemainingFromula
    FROM
       cteSplitFormula
    WHERE 
       LEN(RemainingFromula) > 0

)

, ctePartsValues AS (
    SELECT
       sf.IDNUM
       ,sf.TimeDimensionDate
       ,REPLACE(sf.FormulaItem,'ImportReplaced','Import -') AS FormulaItem
       ,ISNULL(m.AttributeValue,0) AS ReplacementValue
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sf.IDNUM ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS [ReplacementOrderID]
    FROM
       cteSplitFormula sf
       FULL OUTER JOIN #MathLogicTable m
       ON REPLACE(sf.FormulaItem,'ImportReplaced','Import -') = LTRIM(RTRIM(m.INPUTName))
       AND sf.TimeDimensionDate = m.TimeDimensionDate
)

, cteRecursiveDataSource AS (
    SELECT
       m.IDNUM
       ,REPLACE(m.Formula,pv.FormulaItem,pv.ReplacementValue) as Formula
       ,pv.ReplacementOrderID
    FROM
       #MathLogicTable m
       INNER JOIN ctePartsValues pv
       ON m.IDNUM = pv.IDNUM
       AND pv.ReplacementOrderID = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       rds.IDNUM
       ,REPLACE(rds.Formula,pv.FormulaItem,pv.ReplacementValue) as Formula
       ,pv.ReplacementOrderID
    FROM
       cteRecursiveDataSource rds
       INNER JOIN ctePartsValues pv
       ON rds.IDNUM = pv.IDNUM
       AND rds.ReplacementOrderID + 1 = pv.ReplacementOrderID
)

, cteIdentifyRowWithLastReplacementStatement AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IDNUM ORDER BY ReplacementOrderId DESC) as FinalRow
    FROM
       cteRecursiveDataSource
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cteIdentifyRowWithLastReplacementStatement
WHERE
    FinalRow = 1
```

Comment: hi matt... thanks for the help... im just stuck with the first half of the code... i have created a table valued function to split formula based on delimilters but what does it inner joins with .... formula ?

Comment: Hi matt... I tried this one but could'nt make it... somewhere the concept hits a mistake.... i have modified code to do a runtime check for this... let me know if you could help....

Comment: sure.. Do you want me to make this as new post  ?

Comment: hi matt the above code is working but it's not complete coz we are getting zeros for some idnum's